# Append to Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Is there a way to accomplish this? For example I'm trying to have a dynamic dropdown menu that lists year numbers starting with the current year. All solutions I have found don't work for Bootstrap 5, only native html, so the dropdown looks out of place.

Comment: Please include your code and the solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the code from [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/):

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Don't forget to import javascript links of bootstrap to your project. [starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: this doesn't append with javascript, this just creates a dropdown

Comment: when you install bootstrap you have to import also js scripts. Look [starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)